# Identify user (moderator/chat_by - who sent a message) in page's conversation - Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-messages

I'm using Facebook API to get messages data from a page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/conversation/messages)

By now, I can only get Page Name as Sender's name, I want to identify exactly which moderator sent out the message, Is there a way to do that?

I found a [similar unresolved question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69739281/facebook-conversation-api-sent-by)

Please help, Thank you!

Comment: Still doesn't look like there is, no.

Comment: How about get user info (`from` field) from Facebook comment (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/comment). I can not access the field. May I need any permission? Do you know @CBroe